# How to make selenium RC tests run in multiple browsers (using java & eclipse & selenium grid)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I have test cases written in Java in Eclipse that are currently working perfectly with selenium grid but only in one browser at a time. How do I make it run with multiple browsers simultaneously? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If selenium grid is already running, you're halfway done.

As you might know, selenium grid automatically distributes the tests on all registered nodes. If only one browser is opening at a time, it probably means you're not executing your tests in parallel - they are probably executing sequentially.

What you need to do now is to **run your tests in parallel**. If you are using maven, you could configure [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) to run the tests in multiple threads for you (works both with JUnit 4.7+ and TestNG):

### Using Maven:

If you are using Maven, add the following snippet to your `<plugins>` section in your pom.xml (change it according to your needs - see [doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### Without Maven:

See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running